# How to detect filesystem events with ruby

Tags: ruby, events, filesystems

I'd like to watch filesystem events for file and directory using ruby.

Now I'm using Guard. 
But it detects only file events.

Is there any way to detect file system events including directory events?

Answer (score 6):

You can [rb-inotify](https://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify) for watching filesystem events for a particular directory
eg :

```
require "rb-inotify"

DIR_TO_WATCH = "/tmp/notify-dir"

notifier = INotify::Notifier.new

notifier.watch(DIR_TO_WATCH, :create, :delete) do |event|
  puts "Create event for: #{event.name}" if event.flags.include?(:create)
  puts "Delete event for: #{event.name}" if event.flags.include?(:delete)
end

notifier.run
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

For **supporting multiple platforms** you can try [Listen](https://github.com/guard/listen), this is made by the guys at Guard and supports  Mac OS X 10.6+, Linux, BSD([some problems are there](https://github.com/guard/listen#on-bsd)) and Windows.

From documentation:

```
listener = Listen.to('dir/to/listen', 'dir/to/listen2') do |modified, added, removed|
  puts "modified absolute path: #{modified}"
  puts "added absolute path: #{added}"
  puts "removed absolute path: #{removed}"
end
listener.start # not blocking
sleep
```

Comment: Sorry for not explaining sufficiently.

I'm planing to use it on windows, mac, and linux.  

Dose it work on multi platform?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I've tried the gem Listen, but it can't detect directory events. Dose it need any settings to enable directory event detection?